# vertical-center images using either jquery or css

Tags: jquery, css

I have this particular problem. I am loading images dynamically, and each one of them has different height. I would like the image to be positions vertically in the middle of the container. Here is how the html is structured

```
<div class="item">
<div class="photo">
<img />
</div>
<div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if there is a possibility to do that with either jquery or css. The height of the .photo is 140px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1: CSS Background

If `div.photo` has a fixed width and height, either remove the `<img />` element and add `style="background:url(&quot;http://example.com/pic.png&quot;) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;"` to the specific div, **or** replace the `<img />` element by:

```
<div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:url(&quot;http://example.com/pic.png&quot;) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;"></div>
```

The image will be vertically centered now. The image will not shrink when it's too large, though.

#### Method 2: CSS + HTML

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7ekF/). The photo will be centered, and aligned vertically.

HTML:

```
<div class="photo">
    <div class="middle-photo">
        <div class="center-photo">
            <img src="http://files.fosswire.com/2008/04/ubuntu_logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middle-photo {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.center-photo {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do it in 2 ways :**

using javascript to determine the windows size etc

or you can put it in a table and use vertical-align property

my final suggest is to use Js and calculate the margin-left  & margin-top attribute.